# Node.js: connect.static/express.static or a 'standard' webserver?

Tags: node.js, nginx, express, connect

**Is the connect.static middleware considered robust enough for serving static content that's more than just stylesheets and scripts?**

(I'm thinking of situations such as serving a large number of image files).

**Or would it be more appropriate to run a 'standard' webserver, like nginx, alongside for static content?**

Answer (score 4):

Sort of a loaded question. It's fine until it isn't.

These static middlewares are convenience methods for mostly-dynamic sites. You can always switch up to using a [Node.js-based static content server](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static), and then further to NginX, which is designed to primarily serve static content, and then when that's not enough, you can set up an NginX reverse proxy server to several NginX servers if disk I/O becomes a bottleneck, and you can use [Round-Robin DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) to further improve things if your reverse proxy server can't handle the number of incoming connections and/or you want to distribute the hosting globally, and you can always pay for all of this engineering work by hosting your static content in a CDN.

So, do some benchmarks. How many requests do you expect your website to have? What percentage would be static versus dynamic content? How much of this static content could conceivably be cached by the end-user on a second request? How big are these files, on average?

Once you can calculate something like "4000 requests per second with a total throughput of 30MB per second", then you can decide where along the sliding scale of hosting static content you should build out for.

Comment: +1 you're unlikely to hit the boundaries. And if you do, switch to a CDN instead.

Comment: I mostly answered the sliding scale for serving static content in case he wasn't allowed to use a CDN (a large intranet site for a corporation [ha!], or a business where the served content is part of the market value of the company and should be tightly controlled [Facebook]).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I didn't intend it to be a loaded question.  It's just that things like nginx have good established reputations for static content serving, while connect.static seems to be a bit of an unknown quantity.  I'm not at the stage were I can do benchmarks yet, and yes CDNs may be an option in the future (and would of course solve the problem), but I am assessing local solutions for now. I was hoping initially to learn a little from other people's experiences with static content service from node.

Comment: Personal experience with a micro Amazon AWS instance: Express' static middleware gives about 4500 responses per second for a small file, and Lighttpd gives us about 7000 responses per second. NginX should be around the same performance as Lighttpd -- a little over 50% faster for small files. Large files are basically bandwidth-limited.